# Running local integration test with Localstack and Docker-Compose gives: NetworkingError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose, localstack

1. Ran a docker-compose.yml that sets up localstack
2. Ran a script to create an AWS stack

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --endpoint http://localhost:4581 --region us-east-1 --stack-name localBootstrap --template-body file://localstack-bootstrap-cf.yaml --parameters ParameterKey=Environment,ParameterValue=localstack --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

3. Ran Terraform commands to create the AWS resources in Localstack. All good.
4. Ran serverless offline command to set local AWS NodeJs lambdas. All good.
5. But then when running the integration tests got errors and below message

```
NetworkingError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Answer (score 0):

What fixed the problem was to run

```
aws configure
```

and configure AWS locally, even only dummy values were needed.